# Can someone explain this matplotlib pcolormesh quirk?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plotting an array with pcolormesh with x and y data removes a row of the data

To illustrate what I mean, see the following:

```
data = np.random.random([5,5])
plt.pcolormesh(data)
```

results in this 5x5 grid:
[image]

But if I want to define the x an y axes for the data like this, pcolormesh creates a 4x4 grid, with the top and right rows missing...

```
plt.pcolormesh(range(5), range(5), data)
```

[image]

In order to get the full 5x5 plot, I have to do

```
plt.pcolormesh(range(6), range(6), data)
```

[image]

Is this just a quirk of pcolormesh? Or can someone explain the reasoning why pcolormesh behaves this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you see is expected. The [pcolor documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html#matplotlib-pyplot-pcolor) states for
`pcolor(X, Y, C, **kwargs)`:

> Ideally the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C; if the dimensions are the same, then the last row and column of C will be ignored.

The same is of course true for `pcolormesh`.

I'm not sure if this is the place to discuss whether this behaviour is a "quirk", but the underlying idea is that the grid defines the edges of the colored faces. Just as on a number line you have `n` numbers and `n-1` intervals in between.

It actually makes sense to define the edges by the grid, because `pcolormesh` also allows for unequally spaced grids  which would be impossible to define otherwise.

[image]